# Toggle JSON serializers for different endpoints

Tags: java, jackson, jersey, serialization

In `Jersey`'s endpoints I want to return same `DTO` but serialise it differently by using different serialisers: different `Date` formats needed.

```
public class Foo {
    private Date foo;

    public Foo() {
        this.foo = new Date();
    }

    public Date getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(Date foo){
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}

public class MyEndpointsUnix {
    @GET
    @Path("/dateAsUnix")
    public Foo getDateAsUnix() {
        return new Foo();
    }

}

public class MyEndpointsUTC {
    @GET
    @Path("/dateAsUTC")
    public Foo getdateAsUTC() {
        return new Foo();
    }
}
```

I suppose it should be possible to change serialisers for response manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `OOP` point of view we can create new class for every kind of `view`:

```
class UnixFoo extends Foo {

    private Foo foo;

    public UnixFoo(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @Override
    public Date getFoo() {
        return foo.getFoo();
    }

    // other getters
}
```

and in our controller we can:

```
public class MyEndpointsUnix {
    @GET
    @Path("/dateAsUnix")
    public Foo getDateAsUnix() {
        return new UnixFoo(new Foo());
    }
}
```

Of course this solution has a downside that we need to copy our `DTO` classes. To avoid that we can use [Jackson MixIn Annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations#highlighter_85546). To do that we should create new interface:

```
interface UnixFooMixIn {

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    Date getFoo();
}
```

and enrich `ObjectMapper` with it:

```
public class MyEndpointsUnix {
    @GET
    @Path("/dateAsUnix")
    public String getDateAsUnix() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        mapper.addMixIn(Foo.class, UtcFooMixIn.class);

        return mapper.writeValueAsString(new Foo());
    }
}
```

In this case we need to change our method signature and return `String`. Also we can create this `ObjectMapper` once and use it as singleton. For each kind of `view` we need to define new `interface` and new `ObjectMapper` instance.